# Use command line LibreOffice convert to transform TIFF into PNG

Tags: png, tiff, libreoffice

I am currently using LibreOffice to convert WMF and EMF files into PNGs with no problems but when I try to run the same command on TIFF files:

```
soffice -headless -convert-to png -outdir tmp/ image1.tiff
```

the image transforms correctly but I get a much bigger canvas. Basically it looks like if the image was inserted into an A4 page and the final image is a "page screen capture"

Is there a way by which I can control the "canvas size"?

Comment: Hmm - is there a special reason for using LO for this task? I would expect Imagemagick / convert doing a better job in matters of graphics conversion.

Comment: The main reason is that I already use LibreOffice and I would like to avoid the installation of imageMagik (if possible). The "convert" transformation is fine, it is just the canvas size that gets changed.

Comment: Ok - but then i can't help. AFAIK, LO graphics export filter doesn' support any command line options. You may try to edit the export options by opening LO Draw and exporting a png to tiff manually. With some luck, LO keeps the settings when exporting using the command line. But i *strongly* recommend using ImageMagick / convert.